# Why is collect splitting the zero order term with higher order terms?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials

For some strange reason `Collect` for me is not collecting the highest order terms in my polynomial. Consider

```
x = -1 + n  (p0 - (m + ( (k - n) n ))) - a (1 + m (p0 - (m + ( (k - n) n ))) )
Collect[x, n]
```

Of which the output is

> -1 - a + a m^2 + (-k - a m) n^2 + n^3 - a m p0 + n (-m + a k m + p0)

Notice how the n^3 term and n^2 term split the zeroth order term. Why is this?

Comment: That's `Plus[]` just sorting its arguments. If you want a different *display* (i.e. not for subsequent manipulation), try `PolynomialForm[Collect[x, n], TraditionalOrder -> True]`.

Comment: Can you make that an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

As J. M. commented some months ago `Plus` is reordering your terms.  Try:

```
Collect[x, n, # &, Defer[+##] &]
```

> ```
> (-1 - a + a m^2 - a m p0) + n (-m + a k m + p0) + (-k - a m) n^2 + n^3
> ```